# Dialogflow: Agent metadata not found for agentId

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to use Dialogflow's `detect_intent` in Python and I keep getting:

> 404 com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: Agent metadata not found for agentId: ####-####-####-####-####

Here's a snippet of my code:

```py
import google.cloud.dialogflow as dialogflow

from CONFIG import DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'credentials/dialogflow.json'

def predict_intent(text, language):
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
    text_input = dialogflow.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language)
    query_input = dialogflow.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)  # ERROR
    return response.query_result.intent.display_name
```

I tried running the function multiple times and some of them succeed, but most fall in the exception.

I can train the bot using the same interface and it works fine.

I'm using Python 3.7 and the following Google Cloud modules: google-api-core==2.0.1, google-auth==2.0.2, google-cloud-dialogflow==2.7.1, googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0.

Comment: I tried your code and tested it multiple times on a single intent, on different intents and I did not encounter that error. How did you run your tests for you to get the error?

Comment: I realized the error occurs right after training, so the solution was to wait a couple of minutes and keep trying until the code runs fine.